# select dateadd(ms, CAST (3471725580 AS BIGINT), '1970-01-01 00:00:00.0') error

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select dateadd(ms, CAST (3471725580 AS BIGINT), '1970-01-01 00:00:00.0');
```

Comment: epoch date 2080 convert in sql issue

Query
select dateadd(ms, CAST (3471725580 AS BIGINT), '1970-01-01 00:00:00.0');

Problome 
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

Comment: The second argument of `dateadd` [must be](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments) convertible to `int`. 3471725580 isn't.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That dateadd function is product specific.)

Answer (score 3):

You can separate that really big number of milliseconds intoto seconds and milliseconds to prevent the arithmetic overflow error. Try the below code and see the results:

```
SELECT DATEADD(MILLISECOND, 3471725580 % 1000, DATEADD(SECOND, 3471725580 / 1000, '19700101'))
```

This is result when I run the above code in MS SQL Server:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use bigger date time part:

```
select dateadd(SECOND, CAST (3471725580/1000 AS BIGINT), '1970-01-01 00:00:00.0')
```

Answer (score 0):

`3471725580` is bigger than `bigint` then you have the error.
You can easily use `SECOND` instead of `ms` and then decrease the `3471725580` to `3471726`
(you may loose some accuracy)

Comment: bigint goes all the way to 9223372036854775807.

Answer (score 0):

Making it as safe as possible:

```
declare @ms BIGINT = 3471725580;
-- ms per a week
declare @msw INT = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
select dateadd(ms, @ms % @msw, dateadd(week, @ms / @msw, '1970-01-01 00:00:00.0'));
```